# Script tags being rendered after purification in WYSIWYG

Tags: laravel, sanitization, htmlpurifier

I'm having an issue with using the HTMLPurifier php library. I'm using a  WYSIWYG editor named 'Summernote' for all text areas on my application.

When writing something inside sommernote like:

`<script>alert('test');</script>`

The post data comes through as

`<p>&lt;script&gt;alert('test');&lt;/script&gt;</p>`

However, once this is ran through the HTMLPurifier, it doesn't remove the script tags that are converted into regular characters. So when I go to edit this text inside summernote, it actually runs the script!

Here's an image of what is processed into the editor:

[image: HTML Purifier Issue]

And here is how it's stored inside the database:

[image: HTML Purifier Issue - 2]

If anyone has any ideas please let me know!

EDIT: Also, if I disable the Summernote WYSIWYG editor, the tags are successfully removed from the textarea when cleaning with HTMLPurifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the underlying issue here is a common mistake:

When you're outputting the purified HTML into your WYSIWYG, you need to use `htmlspecialchars()` on it. So, instead of having this in the source code of the rendered page...

```
<textarea ...>
  <p>&lt;script&gt;alert('test');&lt;/script&gt;</p>
</textarea>
```

...you need to have this:

```
<textarea ...>
  &lt;p&gt;&amp;lt;script&amp;gt;alert('test');&amp;lt;/script&amp;gt;&lt;/p&gt;
</textarea>
```

Then the WYSIWYG should function as expected. (If it doesn't, Edward is actually right - you should look into a different editor.)

The reason that's the correct way to do it is because you want *text* in your textarea, not HTML. This is easiest to realise if you consider a scenario without HTML Purifier, and someone entering a `</textarea>` tag, followed by other tags. Those would break out of the `<textarea>`, WYSIWYG or not. So you put a `htmlspecialchars()` around what you're outputting, which is just supposed to be text in the textarea. The fact it can deal with HTML tags directly is a coincidence - it's rather misleading, it would probably be better if it didn't work, but most browsers will still show HTML tags as if they *had* been escaped if you don't do it.

Once the text is properly escaped, *then* the WYSIWYG can come in, to take the text and interpret it as HTML.

See if `htmlspecialchars()` fixes your issue. It should do that, *without* causing side-effects, even if that might seem counter-intuitive to you now.

(Of course, if you already use `htmlspecialchars()` as described, then I'm afraid I don't have an idea off-hand.)

Comment: This was the issue (using `htmlspecialchars()` on output to the editor), I completely forgot about this function. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Sweet. Glad you got it fixed! :)