# HTMLPurifier without htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars, htmlpurifier

I am using HTMLPurifier for simple `Tinymce WYSIWYG`.If I don't use `htmlspecialchars`,would it be open to `XSS Attack`?This is what I'm doing

```
$detail = $purifier->purify($detail);
```

to purify data for that `textarea`.If I use `htmlspecialchars`,it strips all basic tags as well which is not user friendly for an `WYSIWYG` editor.But the problem is,this allows `<script> tag` as well.

And if I change `conf setting` to

```
$config->set('ExtractStyleBlocks.1', true);
```

It doesn't allow `<` and `>` for `<script> tag`.Convert `<` and `>` for `<script>` only.But it shows `<p>This is paragraph</p>` ,`<strong>This text is bold</strong>` and so on.It shouldn't show `<p> and other simple tags` to user,but only the text.

How can I get rid of this problem.

Please help.Thanks for your time.

**Edit**

Here is my HTMLPurifier initialization

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
//$config->set('ExtractStyleBlocks', true);
$config->set('HTML.ForbiddenElements', array('script','style','applet'));
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

getting data from database

```
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1)){
  $id=htmlspecialchars($id);
  $title=htmlspecialchars($title);
  $detail = $purifier->purify($detail);

 $posts.="<div id='date_news'><div id='news_holder$id' class='news_holder'><h3 id='show_title'>".htmlspecialchars($title)."</h3>".$detail."</div>";
```

**HTML for `$detail`**

*At Database*

```
<p><strong>Alu Vazi</strong></p>
<p>I love alu vazi with&lt;script&gt;alert("XSS")&lt;/script&gt;</p>
```

*User screen*

**Alu Vazi**

I love alu vazi with`<script>`alert("XSS")`</script>`

Comment: You can specify what elements to accept with HTML Purifier I think... I'll check and come back.

Comment: What are you purifying? The data as it's being entered into the database or as it's being echoed out into the `<textarea>` ... or both?

Comment: I'm getting data from database,and purifying that data.I have inserted data as it is into database.Not echoing into textarea,but in user's page(screen)

Comment: @CD001 I have updated my question,please have a look

Comment: Can you include the HTML of `$detail`.

Comment: Using bound parameters or bound values? What you've got here looks like it should work - I've got a sneaking suspicion this may have something to do with the fact that, with bound parameters, everything has to be passed by reference; just as an experiment try changing `$detail = $purifier->purify($detail);` to `$cleandetail = $purifier->purify($detail);` (and echo out `$cleandetail` rather than `$detail` of course).

Comment: Oh - scratch that, since you've added the database bit ... it's already escaped into html entities! `<p>I love alu vazi with&lt;script&gt;alert("XSS")&lt;/script&gt;</p>` - there's nothing there to purify.

Comment: @CD001 As `script tag` display on screen,but it doesn't give me alert box.So,is it still open to xss attack?

Comment: @CD001 .Does `prepared statement` change `<script>` tag before inserting data into `database`?That might be the only reason why `<script>` is escaped in my `database`.

Comment: @Coder - prepared statements don't do HTML entity conversion but TinyMCE does, I'm pretty certain it's your WYSIWYG editor that's converting the `<` `>` characters before database insertion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26128263/245790 - this might help you. Basically, purify first, then use htmlspecialchars(), then output the information between the `<textarea>` tags. :)

Comment: @CD001 +1 for ur comment.but do u know,how can I output that on screen safely so that `<script>` would be converted?

Answer (score 0):

OK, following my comment try adding this to your HTML Purifier config, it should be enabled by default, but worth a shot.

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.ForbiddenElements', array('script','style','applet'));
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

**Edit**

```
<p>I love alu vazi with&lt;script&gt;alert("XSS")&lt;/script&gt;</p>
```

You've already escaped the `<script>` tag here so HTML Purifier has nothing to parse. It will be output on the page as a result but you have effectively neutralised the XSS attempt.

In your code something is already escaping HTML characters before saving to the database.

Comment: Can you show your code for HTML Purifier initialization in your question, and also the example HTML you are parsing?

Comment: Looking forward for your help.Thanks

Comment: I don't know how's it happening,because I'm inserting data as plain text into database.But anyway,do you think that,I'm safe from XSS Attack for `WYSIWYG` editor in this case?

Comment: I can't answer that question without sitting next to you and going through all your code. You just have to spend time learning about some aspects of programming and then utilise what you've learnt. It all comes down to knowledge/experience.

Comment: Hi,One more question.Does `prepared statement` change `<script>` tag before inserting data into `database`?That might be the only reason why `<script>` is escaped in my database.

Comment: No a prepared statement would not do this.

Comment: 'It will be output on the page as a result but you have effectively neutralised the XSS attempt.' - almost, but not quite. :) Because of the WYSIWYG, the &gt; and &lt; will be interpreted as < and > (which is how it should function). So the right order of things is to purify first, then use htmlspecialchars(), then output it into the textarea.