# Forbid script tags and event listeners in jqte jQuery text editor using htmlpurifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, htmlpurifier, jqte

I am using jqte to give users of a cms I wrote some WYSIWYG for their content.
To output the content publicly I use htmlPurifier so there is no way, editors will do harm to the visitors of the site.

They could however place

```
<button onclick="alert('this sux')">klick me</button>
```

in the textarea and the next user will find a working button.

```
<script>evilcode</script>
```

is even executed.

Has anyone dealt with this before me and can give me a hint to an elegant solution here?

Comment: Sanitize it at server is most common approach. Anyone can manipulate what is sent to server and that is the only safe place to do it

Comment: I don't have a problem on the server and surely I could change all html/js to no html/js but I'd rather do it leaving the jqte intact.

Comment: Not sure what most of that comment means

Comment: jqte is based on using some tags and interpreting them. 
If I striptag (or otherwise 'uncode') the input, the wysiwyg functionality is lost. I guess, there will be a way by manually filtering all the eventlisteners and make a whitelist for allowed tags etc. I just thought someone might have gone through this before me.

Comment: you don't `strip tag`...you sanitize ...big difference

Comment: actually I rush the code through htmlpurifier before putting it back in the textarea again. *sigh*  I might take a deeper look into the documentation

Comment: I use TinyMCE not jqte but face the same challenge. TinyMCE allows you to forbid things, but you still can't trust the HTML you receive. I store exactly what I receive in the DB, then sanitize it _for output_, and depending on the output "target" (output to a .txt file vs. to a web page) eliminating (escaping) tags that I don't allow.  My approach uses jTidy to parse, validate, and fix broken tags, then uses my own "TagRenderer"s to write the final output. For example, my `ScriptTagRenderer` escapes, while `StrongTagRenderer` doesn't.

Comment: I answered my own question - so for me it is settled. I recommend, you replace the &lt; and &gt; with < and >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say you don't have `htmlspecialchars()` around the output when you load previously submitted data into your form - you should, though, since **it's still *text* for a *textarea***. The text is being interpreted as HTML by your WYSIWYG, but don't confuse that for actual HTML. :)

As consolation, know that this confusion is extremely common ([it keeps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410850/htmlpurifier-not-working-with-froala-editor-wysiwyg) [happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104203/htmlpurifier-without-htmlspecialchars/29104384#comment46485312_29104384)) and there are many, many people with a problem exactly like the one you describe.

Let's take a look at the workflow and where things likely went wrong:

### Problem Workflow

When someone writes `<tag>` into the richtext within your WYSIWYG field with the WYSIWYG loaded, the editor sees that someone wants to put the HTML `&lt;tag&gt;` into the message.

When someone writes **bold text** into richtext, the editor sees that someone wants to put the HTML `<b>bold text</b>` (or comparable) into the message.

Meanwhile, in the background, the text `&lt;tag&gt; <b>bold text</b>` (or whatever) is being stored in a *textarea*. To preserve the text as *text* in an HTML context, it's encoded with HTML-encoding, invisibly turning it into `&amp;lt;tag&amp;gt; &lt;b&gt;bold text&lt;/b&gt;`.

However, when your submit button is pressed, the *text* of the textarea (`&lt;tag&gt; <b>bold text</b>`) is sent to your server, since the form data itself of course isn't HTML encoded (it's not embedded in HTML) - it's just a set of keys and values, and you wanted the value of the textarea.

Now, when you're building HTML in your server-side application to load up the message again for further editing, you want the *value* of the field to be HTML encoded, since you're putting that value into an HTML context. What you were previously doing is creating `<textarea>&lt;tag&gt; <b>bold text</b></textarea>`, which is putting HTML into an HTML context. In basically all browsers, this makes the textarea take on the *value* `<tag> <b>bold text</b>`. Ouch! (Imagine if someone had `</textarea>` as part of their raw message!)

To everyone's confusion, WYSIWYG editors are unfortunately good at nonetheless displaying approximately what you wanted, there. For most use-cases you won't even notice the difference, which is why this error is so widespread.

When building the HTML of your page, though, you *actually* want to build `<textarea>&amp;lt;tag&amp;gt; &lt;b&gt;bold text&lt;/b&gt;</textarea>`. This makes the textarea take on the *value* `&lt;tag&gt; <b>bold text</b>` - that's exactly what you wanted.

### Your [Current Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34819332/245790), And Why It Breaks

The solution you currently have runs the submitted text through `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, which turns `&lt;tag&gt;` into `<tag>`, thereby letting HTML Purifier eliminate it. You no longer need to worry about `&lt;tag&gt;` being interpreted as `<tag>` in the context of the WYSIWYG.

However, you unfortunately have two problems:

**1)** People can no longer submit messages *about tags* without HTML Purifier stripping them. Depending on the use case of your textarea, this may not be a problem. Maybe you don't want people to be able to submit HTML messages like `If you're making your own website, you can use &lt;script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js" language="javascript"&gt; instead of hosting the jquery.js yourself` - with your current solution, a message like that would be sanitised to `If you're making your own website, you can use  instead of hosting the jquery.js yourself` by HTML Purifier.

**2)** **Much more dangerously**, people can still hack you! Try writing the *text* `&lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt;` into your editor (so the editor sees the *HTML* you want to submit as `&amp;lt;script&amp;gt;alert(1);&amp;lt;/script&amp;gt;`) and hitting submit. Your solution will turn this into `&lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt;`, which you'll put into your `<textarea>` and then you're unfortunately back to square one.

### Actual Solution

Remove your `htmlspecialchars_decode()` solution (but keep purifying!) and instead put `htmlspecialchars()` around your output. Your WYSIWYG will still work and you won't bypass HTML Purifier's sanitation any more.

Comment: If this answer is confusing, here's an answer to an identical problem I gave two years ago which may be less confusingly written: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26128263/245790

Comment: This is one of the best and most deconfusing answers I ever got here. Thank you very much!

Comment: htmlspecialchars (or htmlentities) works well for the frontend output. 
But in the wysiwyg editor your 'hack' &lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt; becomes <script>alert(1);</script> and so is thrown away in the next sanitation round upon storing. I am so glad I don't need my solution to contain/explain/display html tags right now.

Answer (score 0):

jqte masks the tags so

```
<
```

becomes

```
&lt;
```

and is missed by HTMLpurifier. So before You purify you need to decode all html masking. You can do that by

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_HTML5);
```

here is my complete class into which you can throw strings or arrays, provided you have installed htmlpurifier (i.e. using composer)

```
class cleanWysiwyg
{
    private $allowTags = array('b','i','u');
    private $purifier;

    public function __construct()
    {
          $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
          $config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', $this->allowTags );
          $this->purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    }

      public function cleanup ( &$dirty )
      {

        if ( !is_array($dirty) )
          {
        /*do this to prevent some clever workarounds enabled by wysiwyg or bored coders*/
        $dirty = htmlspecialchars_decode($dirty, ENT_HTML5); 
            $dirty = $this->purifier->purify( $dirty );
            return;
          }
          /*if we have an array we call ourselfes for each element*/
        foreach ( $dirty as &$element ){
          $this->cleanup($element);
        }
      }
}
```

Works as a firstaid but still hackable, please see answer marked as solution.
This answer is left here to make it easier as a useful context for the solution.